# Do you find that corporate buzzwords or heavy jargon gets in the way of software project communication?

Tags: communication, terminology

Do you find that corporate buzzwords or heavy management jargon gets in the way of software project communication? for example using words such as

- Mainstreaming
- Holistic
- Contestability
- Synergies
- etc.

Would you rather see a initiative within the industry to put a stop to jargon such as this to help people communicate better and keep project communication in plain English? Is it even a problem? What are your thoughts/anecdotes?

Comment: No clue.  It would require a survey, with a broad frame of reference, to assess the overall impact/s of such epistemological constructs upon the various sets and groups of interested and/or impacted parties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually like buzzwords, **when they are used in moderation.**

They became buzzwords for a practical reason: Even though the concepts may be very complex and/or abstract, there is a consensus on the meaning. So with only one word, you can convey a whole lot of information to a large group of people. I see it as a form of encapsulation of information.
(Notice the use of the slightly outdated buzzword *encapsulation*?)

Of course, that is exactly the reason why many people start to abuse them: They only convey the general concept (i.e. why it's great to do FizzBuzz), and avoid discussing the messy details (i.e. why it won't work). 
And since using a buzzword gives the impression that you are deeply familiar with the subject at hand, it can be used to silence others in the discussion.

**Conclusion**:
Buzzwords are ok - if they are used in the right way. If you want to improve your team communication, train them in the proper use of buzzwords.

Comment: I think what you describe first are technical terms while only the second qualifies as buzzwords.

Comment: But a technical term can very well be a buzzword, too.

Answer (score 2):

I think some kind of industry-wide initiative would be impractical as jargon is in the eye of the beholder.

I think all you can do is make sure that you don't use buzzwords yourself even when communicating with people who do.  For example, use the word "people" when talking to a Project Manager who refers to you and your colleagues as "resources".

Answer (score 2):

The use of technical language can both help and hinder project team's progress, depending on appropriateness.

First it's necessary to point out that what is considered "too technical" [depends purely on perspective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590254/why-programming-is-called-technical-and-lets-say-banking-isnt-closed). "[Mainstreaming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mainstreaming)" is as much of a technical term, as SSD,  CORBA and SOAP. Something that sounds as jargon nonsense to one person is actually a shortcut to communicate a complex concept for another.

Software development as a rule is cross-domain activity involving in addition to the software knowledge one or more technical user domains. It is a big mistake to assume that sales, marketing, management and banking (just to name a few fields often incorrectly considered "non-technical") haven’t developed and advanced their own complex body of knowledge, in other word — technology: sales technology, marketing technology, management technology and banking technology.

And it’s project manager’s responsibility to facilitate productive communication between representatives of different technical domains. Some suggestions:

- Make handy a project dictionary that can be accessed and updated by everyone involved.
- Ensure that common denominator language used for cross-domain documentation (i.e. functional specs).
- Introduce domain specific terms only when necessary, but then always provide a brief explanation of the meaning (don’t “build from scratch” —leverage the wealth of online encyclopaedias by linking where possible).
- Make sure that there is common understanding amongst the project team of the key terms.
- Remember that what is considered “technical” depends purely on perspective and you need to facilitate communication in all directions, not just one-way (which is often from software developers to business users).
- At the end the software will have to work in the realm of users and you have to make a judgement on how much the UI will rely on specific domain language (this is going to be a trade off between easiness-to-learn and usage-efficiency).

Answer (score 2):

Technical jargon (ORM, TDD etc.) makes one's speech *more* precise. Corporate buzzwords (aka management jargon), on the other hand, are designed to be able to express vague ideas when full information is not available.

As such, management jargon serves its purpose pretty well, in the sense that it does allow managers to effectively communicate about thins they have very limited understanding of. That said, good manager knows when NOT use the jargon, such as when talking with developers, or with executives, both of whom hate bullshit.

Based on the above, the (Anti-)Buzzword Movement, should rather increase awareness of the proper usage and application of management jargon, and encourage proper information encapsulation only with appropriate auditory.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I think that the jargon should be used more.  I see this occurring more and more and IT people want to simply hide behind the technical elements of the world and act like it is completely the business folks responsibility to speak more geeky.

I'll be honest, speaking more ***GEEK*** is not something that the business people can do and you should not want that to occur.  Learn the jargon.  Become one with the jargon.  Own the jargon.  Then the next time you are discussing things, you'll not be back pedaling.

Take ownership of the business terms and apply them to the technical side of things...

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with "holistic" or "synergy"? These are normal plain English words.

Answer (score 1):

Every field has it's own jargon, and that must tell us something - people like having special words, phrases or assigning special meanings to existing words that are only relevant within their own field. I suspect if we went back to the pyramids, there'd be a full set of architectural and building phrases that your average Egyptian just wouldn't understand. So banning jargon just wont work, creating an FAQ and glossary normally do the trick.

BTW This must be a case of pots and kettles. Does anyone outside IT think phrases like - "...We'll use an ORM, and then WCF will talk over HTTPS, throw in a bit of AJAX and some clever CSS on the client and we're laughing ..."

Comment: "Does anyone outside IT...". But of course. Have you heard for example ppl from investment banks talk? You're phrase sounds plain English comparing to them.

Comment: It sounds plain English to you - just as the banker talk does to the bankers.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. Since managers only talk in general, and we as developers want to understand the precise meaning. I personally fall asleep trying to read abstract writing filled with buzzwords.

The worst being SOA. Neither academic folks nor managers understand it though both use it extensively.

Comment: SOA, *sigh*. I'm currently maintaing a set .NET SOAP WebServices. Someone had the "brilliant" idea of having a WS method for each component method. Obviously, nobody asked *who* would use the webservice, *what* it's meant to do and *how* it was supposed to do it. Someone read about SOA and wanted webservices right away.

Comment: Ooops, I really meant a set *of*...

Answer (score 1):

I can't stand buzzwords.  One person's "encapsulation" is another's Orwellian destruction of language.  Buzwords appeal to the same people who like "decks" rather than memos.  For something to act as a representation of many possible things [e.g. "leveraging resources" can mean pretty well anything from using double-sided printing options to drafting people for the Army] there is necessarily going to be a dilution of meaning.  If a senior lawyer in my firm were to ask me to "leverage the resources, then run it up the flagpole to get the ducks in line", I'd know that he was tossing back the Johnny Walker at lunch.

Conversely, if I were to respond to a senior partner's memo request with emtpy catch phrases such as those above, I'd be fired on the spot for being an idiot - and rightly so.  Too bad the rest of the white collar world isn't like that.

Grouchy Old-fashioned Gen X'r

Answer (score 1):

I'm OK with buzzwords so long as all the stakeholders (see what I did there?) are clear on the shared meaning of each word/phrase.

Answer (score 1):

In general I think that buzzwords are good when used for encapsulating ideas and concepts. it simplifies communication between people who understand the words. However, I draw the line when people use a buzzword when a perfectly normal word would do. I know someone that will say they were "On an Audio" when they mean phone calls or say "dialogging" instead of talking. It makes me want to hit them. Hard!